# Formula to search a range/array in Sheet2 for values in Sheet1 and return values found in Sheet2 but not in Sheet1?

Tags: google-sheets

I have three sheets. Sheet1 contains a column of data (player names), Sheet2 contains an array of player names associated with each other, and Sheet3 is currently blank. I'd like to figure out what formula to use in Sheet3 to search the array in Sheet2 for all names *not* in the column in Sheet1, and then return those in Column A in Sheet 3. Names in the array may be redundant, if that matters.

I'm unsure of the formula to employ; Index/Match doesn't seem to fit the bill, and neither does VLookup.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array MATCH to return an array of just the cells that do not appear in Sheet1 (other cells will be blank):

`=ArrayFormula(IF(ISNA(MATCH(Sheet2!A:E,Sheet1!A:A,0)),Sheet2!A:E,))`

Then you reach the main hurdle here, which is to convert a 2D range into a single column of values. This may be achieved with:

`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(IF(ISNA(MATCH(Sheet2!A:E,Sheet1!A:A,0)),Sheet2!A:E,)&CHAR(9)),CHAR(9))))`

Then, if you wish, you can convert that to just unique values:

`=ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(IF(ISNA(MATCH(Sheet2!A:E,Sheet1!A:A,0)),Sheet2!A:E,)&CHAR(9)),CHAR(9)))))`

Comment: When I enter the first ArrayFormula into A2 on Sheet3, I get "Error: Circular dependency detected."

Comment: Sorry, there were some pretty serious typos there :-/ (fixed).

Comment: Alright. On entering the third formula, it appears to simply transpose quite the line of blank spaces. I'm assuming this has to do with the `CHAR(9)`s, but I've no idea how to fix it; removing them creates a parsing error.